# Sending XML Web Request

Tags: c#, xml, web

We are currently working on a connection to a Web API via XML requests. Our XML statement is as far as correct and also the URL is correct. Nevertheless we receive the following error from the server:

> The remote server has returned an error: (403) Inadmissible.

Is there at least one way to get a more detailed error message?
By the way, the API is not from us so we don't have access to the logs of the backend.

XML Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <OTA_PingRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="3.3" TimeStamp="2020-12-09T13:53:57" PrimaryLangID="en" Target="Production">
  <EchoData><![CDATA[Hello World]]></EchoData>
</OTA_PingRQ>
```

Web Call:

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
            {
                var data = new NameValueCollection();
                data["otaRQ"] = xml;

                var response =
                wb.UploadValues("http://backend.cultuzz.com:7380/cultswitch/processOTA",
            "POST", data);
                string responseInString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
                MessageBox.Show(responseInString);
            }
```

Comment: The response headers may have more information, but you only get what the service provides. If the code is accurate, you do not have the permission to do the operation.

Comment: A http [403 is forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403). So you obviously need to implement some form of authentication to access this resource.

Comment: Using your xml and the given url in a postman request works fine, so check your  `data` once again

Comment: with your exact code I get a 450 No value to echo

Comment: I think the server want HTTPS and you are using HTTP.  Your URL is http://backend.cultuzz.com:7380/cultswitch/processOTA and using a different URL (as other people suggest) doesn't make any sense.  You need to get working with your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use the ping example as documented [here](https://cultswitch.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/CultSwitch_3.4.0_Excerpt_For_Distributors.pdf) it works. Change your xml to this:

```
string xml = @"<OTA_PingRQ xmlns=""http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"" 
    Version=""3.30"" TimeStamp=""2011-07-24T10:07:24"" Target=""Production""> 
    <EchoData><![CDATA[Hello World!!]]></EchoData> </OTA_PingRQ>";
```

response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OTA_PingRS PrimaryLangID="en" Target="Production"
    TimeStamp="2020-12-09T13:46:19" Version="3.00" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <Success/>
    <EchoData><![CDATA[Hello World!!]]></EchoData>
</OTA_PingRS>
```

Comment: Hello Crowcoder,
thanks for your fast answer.

But why is your XML working? It looks exactly like ours. 
Is it becouse of the xmlns Attribute? Or maybe becouse of invisible formatting symbols?

Comment: @Cytexal I've never heard of this API before seeing your question but apparently the namespace is important. The documentation also shows a different URL so you might want to see if you are using their current recommended method.